# Imorting zero_gradients from torch.autograd.gradcheck

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to replicate the code [here](https://github.com/LTS4/DeepFool/blob/master/Python/deepfool.py), and I get the following error while running in Google Colab?

> ImportError: cannot import name 'zero_gradients' from
> 'torch.autograd.gradcheck'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/gradcheck.py)

Can someone help me with how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

This seems like it's using a very old version of PyTorch, the function itself is not available anymore. However, if you look at [this commit](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/819d4b2b83fa632bf65d14f6af80a09e7476e87e/torch/autograd/gradcheck.py#L15), you will see the implementation of `zero_gradients`. What it does is simply zero out the gradient of the input:

```
def zero_gradients(i):
    for t in iter_gradients(i):
        t.zero_()
```

Then `zero_gradients(x)` should be the same as [`x.zero_grad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=zero_grad#torch.nn.Module.zero_grad), which is the current API, assuming `x` is a `nn.Module`!

Or it's just:

```
if x.grad is not None:
    x.grad.zero_()
```

Answer (score 0):

My error was:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "make_figures/make_recon_figure_multires.py", line 23, in 
> from dlutils.pytorch import count_parameters   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dlutils/**init**.py",
> line 32, in 
> from dlutils.pytorch.jacobian import jacobian   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dlutils/pytorch/**init**.py",
> line 16, in 
> from dlutils.pytorch.jacobian import jacobian   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dlutils/pytorch/jacobian.py",
> line 2, in 
> from torch.autograd.gradcheck import zero_gradients ImportError: cannot import name 'zero_gradients' from 'torch.autograd.gradcheck'
> (/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/gradcheck.py)

I  basically went to the location:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dlutils/pytorch/
```

and removed the line:

```
from torch.autograd.gradcheck import zero_gradients
```

and added the function to the top:

```
def zero_gradients(i):
    for t in iter_gradients(i):
        t.zero_()
```