# PyTorch 1.9 command equivalent for `zero_gradients`

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

This error comes after the upgrade of my PyTorch version from 1.8 to 1.9.0.

When using this line:

`from torch.autograd.gradcheck import zero_gradients`, I get this error message: `ImportError: cannot import name 'zero_gradients' from 'torch.autograd.gradcheck'`

The command:

`zero_gradients(im)`

is used.

What is the new command equivalent in PyTorch 1.9.0?

Comment: See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68419612/imorting-zero-gradients-from-torch-autograd-gradcheck/68421531#68421531)

Comment: @Ivan yes, this also could be one answer. The accepted version here is Pytorch Version independent.  
I was googling before asking the question and i could not find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function in pytorch named `zero_gradients()`. The nearest similar name is [`zero_grad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad.html). It's instead a function defined in the repo you shared in [auto-attack/autoattack/other_utils.py](https://github.com/fra31/auto-attack/blob/f551404cf7ed1d6e17d3041d5709ad23f6dbf352/autoattack/other_utils.py#L51) .

```
def zero_gradients(x):
    if isinstance(x, torch.Tensor):
        if x.grad is not None:
            x.grad.detach_()
            x.grad.zero_()
    elif isinstance(x, container_abcs.Iterable):
        for elem in x:
            zero_gradients(elem)
```